# <int:pk>/ in my Django new version project doesn't work for some reason

Tags: python, django, django-views, primary-key, django-urls

I am a newbie in Django and trying to create a basic project. I am currently stuck at int:pk/ and for some reason I couldn't link the details page to the school list page. Please help! thanks a lot! Below are the code:
in my urls.py file:

```
app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
path('list/',views.SchoolListView.as_view(), name='list'),
path('<int:pk>/',views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('create/',views.SchoolCreateView.as_view(),name='create'),
path('update/<int:pk>/', views.SchoolUpdateView.as_view(),name='update')
```

]

in my views.py:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['injectme'] = 'Basic injection'
    return context
class SchoolListView(ListView):
    model = models.School

class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
  context_object_name = 'school_detail'
  model = models.School
  query_pk_and_slug=True
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  return render(request,'basic_app/school_detail.html')

class SchoolUpdateView(UpdateView):
  fields = ('name','principal')
  model = models.School
```

in template school_list.html:

```
{% for school in school_list %}
<h2><li><a href="{{ school.id }}">{{school.name}}</a></li></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

in template school.detail.html:

```
<div class="container">
<p><a class='btn btn-warning' href="{% url 'basic_app:update' pk=school_detail.pk %}">Update here</a></p>
```

in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class School(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   principal = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=200)

   def __str__(self):
    return self.name

   def get_absolute_url(self):
     return reverse("basic_app:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Student(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   school = models.ForeignKey(School,related_name='students',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

this is the error that I got:

```
NoReverseMatch at /basic_app/1/
Reverse for 'update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 
''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['basic_app/update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/1/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 
''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['basic_app/update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
Exception Location:  
C:\Users\MyPC\Anaconda3\envs\MydjangoEnv\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in
```

_reverse_with_prefix, line 677
Python Executable:
C:\Users\MyPC\Anaconda3\envs\MydjangoEnv\python.exe
Python Version:  3.8.3
Python Path:
['C:\Users\MyPC\MyDjango\advanced_section\ad_project',

Comment: Looks like the PK is returning blank `{'pk': ''}`, because in your models.py you haven't said what PK is, but appears here as self: `reverse("basic_app:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})`. Perhaps more setup is needed?

Comment: Where do you ue `{% url ... %}` to the `update` view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I extends the template update view to a base.html file: <p><a class='btn btn-warning' href="{% url 'basic_app:update' pk=school_detail.pk %}">Update here</a></p>

Comment: But the name of the variable is `school`, not `school_detail`?

Comment: @zerecees : you mean I need to set up the id?  : id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) ? this is the default set up of Django , it won't add the id column but in my case maybe I need to change ?

Comment: @AnhLuong: no, you iterate over `{% for school in schools %}`, hence the name of the variable that stores the school is `school`, thus it should be `{% url 'basic_app:update' pk=school.pk %}`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  sorry I confused you, I just updated my question as the template {% for school in schools %} is for a page of list of schools and it works fine but the DetailView is the page that I want to click into that 1 school and it will take me to the page of School Details. And I couldn't connect that School List to SchoolDetail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the detail view

```
class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
  context_object_name = 'school'
  model = models.School
  template_name ='basic_app/school_detail.html'
```

And also here you already have the absolute_url defined so in the template you can do like this.

```
 {% for school in school_list %}
<h2><li><a href="{{ school.get_absolute_url}}">{{school.name}}</a></li></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:** The default context name in update view is set for `object` so change it to `school_detail`.

```
class SchoolUpdateView(UpdateView):
  fields = ('name','principal')
  model = models.School
  context_object_name='school_detail'
```

Comment: It's still showing error, there is something wrong with my pk 'update' argument that not found.

Comment: hey, thank you for your help. Yes I did update the name for object in UpdateView, and also I deleted the Get function in class SchoolDetailView and It worked!! For some reason that Get function should not be there. Thanks  a lot everyone !!!